# Notation in thermodynamics derivatives

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, notation, differentiation

In Yung Kuo  Lim's book of exercises in thermodynamics and Stat. Physics I have found more than once the following notation for partial derivatives (ex. 1081 page 79):

$$ \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial L}\right)_S = \frac{\partial(T,S)}{\partial(L,S)} $$

I don't think that this is only a matter of notation, because the authors use it as a way to solve the exercises, not just as a different way to write something.

What does the writing on the RHS of the equation stand for?

EDIT: The author uses both notations, that's why I wondered if the second one has something more to say than the first one. Here's another example of how he uses it:

$$ \left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial H} \right)_S = \frac{\partial(T,S)}{\partial(H,S)} = \frac{\partial(H,T)}{\partial (H,S)} \cdot \frac{\partial(H,M)}{\partial(H,T)} \cdot \frac{\partial(T,S)}{\partial(H,M)} $$

with T the temperature, S the entropy, H the magnetic field and M the magnetization. If it is only a matter of notation, how is it the second one more useful than the first one?

Comment: @PPeg: In most areas that use partial derivatives, the number of variables is the same as the number of dimensions, and $\delta z/\delta x$ is unambiguous. Not for thermodynamics. How would you write it if you didn't use this notation? If you just write $\delta T/\delta L$, how do I know which variable to hold constant? If $T, L, S$ and $P$ are four different variables in a 3-dimensional space, then $\left(\delta T/\delta L\right)_S \neq \left(\delta T/\delta L \right)_P$.

Comment: @PeterShor  That's fine, but doesn't the first notation say that already?  Why the need for the second?

Comment: Question for the OP:  does the author use both notations, or only one of them, and you are filling in the meaning.  If he uses only one, I can understand.  But if he uses both notations at the same time, I'm wondering if he's trying to make some distinction between the two.

Comment: @garyp: sometimes it's useful to actually have a notation for infinitesimals and not just for partial derivatives. Do you complain about unnecessary duplication of notation when people use both $y'$ and $dy/dt$?

Comment: @garyp I edited my question.

Comment: @PeterShor I understand that there is the need to specify which variable to keep constant, I just don't understand why this notation is more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question in Callen, Thermodynamics and Thermo-statistics:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial(u,v,\ldots,w)}{\partial(x,y,\ldots,z)} \equiv \det \left(\matrix{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &\ldots &\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} &\ldots &\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} &\ldots &\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\\}\right),
\end{equation}

which is just a Jacobian matrix.
The following identities hold:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial(u,v,\ldots,w)}{\partial(x,y,\ldots,z)} &= -~\frac{\partial(v,u,\ldots,w)}{\partial(x,y,\ldots,z)}\\
\frac{\partial(u,v,\ldots,w)}{\partial(x,y,\ldots,z)} &=\frac{\partial(u,v,\ldots,w)}{\partial(r,s,\ldots,t)} \frac{\partial(r,s,\ldots,t)}{\partial(x,y,\ldots,z)}\\
\frac{\partial(u,v,\ldots,w)}{\partial(x,y,\ldots,z)} &=1\left/\frac{\partial(x,y,\ldots,z)}{\partial(u,v,\ldots,w)}\right..
\end{align}

The link with thermodynamic relations comes from the identity:

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_{y,\ldots,z} = \frac{\partial(u,y,\ldots,z)}{\partial(x,y,\ldots,z)},
\end{equation}

hence the relation of the example in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the answer: $\frac{\partial(y,x)}{\partial (z,w)}\equiv -\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\Bigr |_{all~other~ variables~ constant}\Bigr/\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\Bigr |_{all~other~ variables~ constant}$. I will explain below why minus sign is required. Whether or not my answer is right, a book with such crappy notation that it requires considerable effort to understand what the notation means is not worth spending your time over. I would recommend Thermodynamics by Callen. In particular read the chapter on Maxwell relations.

I make use of the identity: $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\Bigr |_z=-\frac{\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\Bigr |_x}{\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\Bigr |_y}$. This is where the minus sign comes in.

If my definition is correct then:

$\frac{\partial T}{\partial H}\Bigr |_{S,M}=-\frac{\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\Bigr |_{H,M}}{\frac{\partial H}{\partial S}\Bigr |_{T,M}}=\frac{\partial (T,S)}{\partial (H,S)}$

Taking the expression on the extreme right:

$\frac{\partial (H,T)}{\partial (H,S)}\frac{\partial (H,M)}{\partial (H,T)}\frac{\partial (T,S)}{\partial (H,M)}=-\frac{\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}}{\frac{\partial H}{\partial S}}  \frac{\frac{\partial H}{\partial M}}{\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}}  \frac{\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}}{\frac{\partial H}{\partial M}}=-\frac{\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}}{\frac{\partial H}{\partial S}}=\frac{\partial T}{\partial H}\Bigr |_{S,M}$

where in the intermediate steps I have suppressed names of variables which are held constant during partial differentiation to avoid clumsiness of appearance.

Comment: This definition along with the identity you used seems to work. The book in which I have found this notation is [this](https://www.amazon.com/Solutions-Thermodynamics-Statistical-Universities-Qualifying/dp/9810200560/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1471436891&sr=1-3&keywords=yung-kuo+lim), and it is a book of solved exercises.

Comment: I'm sitting without access to a pencil, so I'm following along in my head.  Looks good, and explains the value of the notation, while reminding me why I did poorly in physical chemistry  (5.61, for those who recognize *that* notation).

Answer (score 2):

The notation stands for the following:
$$
\partial \left( \left[\text{variable  to  differentiate} \right], \left[\text{variable to hold  constant} \right] \right)
$$

As @PeterShor pointed out, a multi-variate system requires one to worry about which variables to hold constant during [partial differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative).

You could equivalently write this as:
$$
\left( \frac{ \partial \left[\text{variable to differentiate} \right] }{ \partial \left[ \text{variable of differentiation} \right] } \right)_{\left[\text{variable to hold constant} \right]}
$$
as there are multiple forms of [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation).

Note that partial derivatives require you to specify with respect to which variables to hold constant but [total derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) differentiate every variable of which the differentiated variable is a function.

**Side Note:**  There is a specific name for the variable in the denomenator, which I am not recalling off hand.  Perhaps a more mathematically inclined individual could help?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what I would like to understand.