# Dependence of internal energy on temperature for an ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, ideal-gas

In an undergraduate thermodynamics book, the authors use the case of free expansion of an ideal gas to argue that the internal energy $U$ of the gas depends only on its temperature $T$. I'm not sure if the authors mean to say that $\biggl(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\biggr)_V = \biggl(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\biggr)_P = 0$ or if $V = V(T)$ and $P = P(T)$ - in other words, all changes in internal energy are ultimately attributable to changes in temperature. I assume it must be the latter.

Supposing it is the former - i.e. $\biggl(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\biggr)_V = \biggl(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\biggr)_P = 0$, then let us consider the adiabatic expansion of a gas from volume $V_1$ to $V_2$. The First Law tells us that

\begin{eqnarray}
 \Delta U &=& Q – W
 \\
 &=& 0 -P(V_2 – V_1) = - P\Delta V
\end{eqnarray}

What am I to conclude from this?

Comment: 1. You must indicate in your partial derivatives what’s being held constant; otherwise, the interpretation is ambiguous. 2. The heat Q disappeared in your derivation. Please consider editing your question to clarify.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Actually, there is no ambiguity. If $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is differentiable in all of its variables, then the definition of the partial $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ ensures that all variables save $x_i$ are held constant. The notational convention of explicitly showing which variables are held constant is unnecessary. Secondly, $Q$ vanishes because an adiabatic process is one in which there is no heat transfer.

Comment: That's not how partial derivatives work in thermodynamics contexts; see [this explanation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/623345/146039), for example.

Comment: Ah, I see! Now it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: So $nC_v\Delta T=-P\Delta V$

Answer (score 1):

$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_{T,N}=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\right)_{T,N}=0$ for the ideal gas. Thus, there's no contradiction with $\Delta U\neq 0$ for pressure–volume work on an closed adiabatic ideal gas system, as the temperature varies.

Answer (score 0):

> In an undergraduate thermodynamics book, the authors use the case of free expansion of an ideal gas to argue that the internal energy $U$ of the gas depends only on its temperature $T$.

It not strictly true that internal energy depends only on the temperature. It also depends on $N$, the number of particles. But, let's assume that $N$ is fixed. (Or, hold it fixed in all partial derivatives).

> I'm not sure if the authors mean to say that $\biggl(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\biggr)_V = \biggl(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\biggr)_P = 0$

No, neither of the above are true.

Remember, for an ideal gas:
$$
U = \frac{3Nk}{2}T = \frac{3}{2}PV\;.
$$

So, for example
$$
\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\right)_V = \frac{3V}{2}\;.
$$

> or if $V = V(T)$ and $P = P(T)$

Well, not really. For example, for an ideal gas we have:
$$
V = \frac{2U}{3P} = \frac{NkT}{P} = V(T,P,N)\;.
$$

> What am I to conclude from this?

That you have made and error in reasoning, as explained above.